# Passing Unique Variable when Sending E-Mail with Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-email

In my Django project I have `leads` which belong to an `organization`. One of my views filters these leads by organization and then e-mails them a message. This message is in the form of an html template.

Currently this is how I do it:

```
# FIRST: get a list of all the emails
leads_email = []

leads = Lead.objects.filter(organization=organization)
for lead in leads:
    if lead.email != None:
        leads_email.append(lead.email)


# SECOND: Django email functions
msg = EmailMessage(subject, 
                  get_template('email_templates/campaign_email.html').render(
                        {
                            'message': message,
                        }
                    ),
                    from_email,
                    bcc=to_list)
msg.content_subtype = "html"
msg.send()
```

However each `lead` has a unique code associated with them, this field is found under `lead.code`. I would like to include this code in the email.

For example if test@mail.com's unique code is "test123", then I want to include that in the email to test@mail.com alone. I am currently doing this by passing though a variable called `message`, however this is not unique and every lead gets the same thing.

Any idea on how I can accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got email content that is specific to each object, you'll have to send the emails individually rather than in bulk. So you just need to include the email code in your loop;

```
leads = Lead.objects.filter(organization=organization)
for lead in leads:
    if lead.email != None:
        msg = EmailMessage(
            subject, 
            get_template('email_templates/campaign_email.html').render(
                {
                    'message': message,
                    'code': lead.code
                }
            ),
            from_email,
            [lead.email, ]
        )
        msg.content_subtype = "html"
        msg.send()
```